# After AJAX call: Array Acces works, but Array Element Access doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, async-await

I am a JavaScript newbie and have a problem regarding an AJAX call to a local JSON file and afterwards accessing elements of the resulting data array. I fetch values called "number" from a local JSON file and put them in an array. **My problem is: I can perfectly well log the whole array, but not single array values with "data[0]".**

After a long search I am now pretty sure that it is an AJAX problem because I can log the element if I put the logging function into a setTimeout. I thought the async-await part would solve this, but apparently it does not. I have tried to use the "return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ..." syntax in makeDataArray() instead, but it doesn't work either. I don't understand why the await-keyword does not wait "long enough" for the makeDataArray() function to finish. Can someone please explain this to me?

In case this is important: I am not allowed to use jQuery, which is why I use the asycn-await construct.

This is the JavaScript:

```
async function makeDataArray() {
        var myNumbers = new Array();
        fetch('../data/someNumbers.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.forEach(element =>{
                    myNumbers.push(element.number);
            })
        })  
        return myNumbers;
}

async function printArrayElements(){
    let data = await makeDataArray();
    console.log(data); //works correctly
    console.log(data[0]); //undefined
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(data[0]);}, //works correctly
        3000);
}

printArrayElements();
```

This is the JSON file:

```
[{
    "number": 10
},
{
    "number": 20
},
{
    "number": 30
}
]
```

Comment: That is not supposed to work at all; your promise chain does not return anything and you do not even return the promise in `makeDataArray`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, the missing return statement was a copy-paste and edit afterwards mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: But doesn't the async keyword in front of a function automatically return a promise? At least I read that in this tutorial https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Yes, but if you have no return statement the promise will not yield your result.

Comment: Your first log works only because [a peculiarity of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays). You're printing the array reference, the array is populated later, so by the time you examine the object in the console, you are seeing is *current* state, not the state it was in when the log was made. The second log is *correct*, since at the time of printing, there is no data. The third one just happens to work after the array is populated. You should just use `return fetch()` in `makeDataArray()`

Comment: In your updated code you need to `await` the `fetch` to fix it, otherwise you return the empty `myNumbers` array directly. But i would not mix `then` and `async` like that.

Comment: @VLAZ ah  thank you, that makes more sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks quite wrong; this is what i would expect if you use `then` chains:

```
function makeDataArray() {
    return fetch('../data/someNumbers.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.map(x => x.number))
}
```

If you use chaining you need to return your result in the last `then`.

Using async/await:

```
async function makeDataArray() {
    const response = await fetch('../data/someNumbers.json');
    const json = await response.json();
    
    return json.map(x => x.number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the code you have posted is not the code you get the console logs with. The `makeDataArray` function does not have any return statement, so it will return a `Promise<void>` - a promise that will resolve into nothing. You probably want to to something like:

```
async function makeDataArray() {
    const data = await fetch('../data/someNumbers.json')
    return await data.json();
}
```